# jquery - filter elements based on matched values from clicked filter option and container element values

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks so much for all your help.  While all three solutions worked, I like Bill's in terms of readability and performance.  As always, I'm amazed by the level of expertise and help here.  REALLY appreciate the help.

**UPDATE:**

Put demo up on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FC4QE/17/

I need to create a filter.  Users click on a brand name link and if there is a match then I need to filter out the other products.  The brand is contained in a product name, so I'm searching for a match and if there is one or many, I need to hide the other products.

I have the following javascipt/jquery code:

```
$(function(){   
    $('#filter-by-brand li a').click(function(){
        // get html string of clicked item
        var brandNameSelected = $(this).html();
        var productContainer = $('#product-collection div.productBoxWrapper');

        // reset products in the view
        if (brandNameSelected == 'All Brands'){
            productContainer.fadeIn("slow");
        }
        // for each product title (a tag)
        $("#product-collection h4 a").each(function(){
            var productTitle = jQuery(this).html();

            // if item clicked is contained inside product title, hide all 
            // products and only show the ones where the title matched
            if(productTitle.indexOf(brandNameSelected) != -1){
                // hide container of all products, this hides all products
                productContainer.fadeOut("slow");
                // then show only ones that match. the problem is that only the one product is 
                // displayed since we're inside the .each. How can I show all  products where product title contains the item clicked? 
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().fadeIn("slow");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I explained everything in the comments inside the code, but basically, while the code works, because I'm showing the products where item clicked is contained inside the .each method, it only shows the last item matched.  How can I show all the matched ones inside the .each or is this impossible and is there another way?

Hope this makes sense and that someone might have some advice!
Thanks.

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you show the HTML that goes with this code, even better, make it a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you make JSFiddle that we can fiddle with?

Comment: why dont you use the html5 data attributes or maybe try to implement the a name tag to suit your needs? <a name="brand_name" > .  $("a[name*=' + search_brand_query + ']");

Comment: Put it up on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FC4QE/17/

Comment: Demo has cleaner html structure from the code I posted here, but the concept and functionality is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the nicest looking results from this:

```
$('#filter-by-brand li a').click(function() 
{
    var brandNameSelected = $(this).html();
    var productContainer = $('#product-collection .product-container');

    if (brandNameSelected == 'All Brands')
    {
        productContainer.fadeIn("slow");
    }
    else {
        $(".product-container")
            .fadeOut(100)
            .delay(100)
            .filter(function() {
              return $(this).html().indexOf(brandNameSelected) > -1;  
            })
            .each(function(index, item) {
                $(item).fadeIn("slow");
            });


    }
});
```

You can play with it at http://jsfiddle.net/tu8tc/1/;

Comment: Thanks Bill, this worked beautifully! I liked this approach both in terms of readability and performance.

Answer (score 1):

For "all brands", bail out. For specific brand names, hide all productContainers unconditionally then selectively fadeIn those that meet the criterion.

```
$(function() {
    $('#filter-by-brand li a').click(function() {
        var brandNameSelected = $(this).html();
        var productContainer = $('#product-collection .product-container');
        if (brandNameSelected == 'All Brands') {
            productContainer.fadeIn("slow");
            return;
        }
        productContainer.hide();
        $("#product-collection h4 a").each(function() {
            var productTitle = $(this).html();
            if(productTitle.indexOf(brandNameSelected) != -1) {
                $(this).closest(".product-container").stop().fadeIn("slow");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

See [update of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FC4QE/20/)

Note how jQuery's `.closest()` avoids the ugly `.parent().parent().parent()`.

`.stop()` is precautionary, just in case a `fadeout()` is already running on the element. Not necessary if this is the only code that animates productContainers.

EDIT...

Or to be concise and more efficient, with judicious use of jQuery's `.filter` you can do almost everything in one statement (though readability suffers):

```
$(function() {
    $('#filter-by-brand li a').click(function() {
        var brandNameSelected = $(this).html();
        $('#product-collection').find('.product-container').hide().end().find('h4 a').filter(function() {
            return (brandNameSelected == 'All Brands') || ($(this).html().indexOf(brandNameSelected) != -1);
        }).closest(".product-container").stop().fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

See [further update to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FC4QE/21/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply hide products that you want filtered out?

```
if(productTitle.indexOf(brandNameSelected) == -1)
{
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut("slow");
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/2Sduq/1/ .